# Proper way to set corARMA() correlation structure for lme {nlme}

Tags: nlme

I have a time series with temperature measures every 5-minutes over ca. 5-7 days. I'm looking to set the correlation structure for my model as I have considerable temporal autocorrelation. I've decided that moving averages would be the best form, but I am unsure what to specify within the `correlation = corARMA(q=?)` part of the model. Here is the following output for `ACF(m1)`:

```
       lag          ACF
1    0  1.000000000
2    1  0.906757430
3    2  0.782992821
4    3  0.648405513
5    4  0.506600300
6    5  0.369248402
7    6  0.247234208
8    7  0.139716028
9    8  0.059351579
10   9 -0.009968973
11  10 -0.055269347
12  11 -0.086383590
13  12 -0.108512009
14  13 -0.114441343
15  14 -0.104985321
16  15 -0.089398656
17  16 -0.070320370
18  17 -0.051427604
19  18 -0.028491302
20  19  0.005331508
21  20  0.044325557
22  21  0.083718759
23  22  0.121348020
24  23  0.143549745
25  24  0.151540265
26  25  0.146369313
```

It appears that there is highly significant autocorrelation in the first ca. 7 lags. See also the attached images: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBLBb.png)[Residuals] & [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9sXH.png)[Model]

Would this mean I set the `correlation = corARMA(q=7)`?

Comment: can't tell you if your suggested code is correct. But the R package "sandwich" has a function to estimate robust standard errors in the presence of heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation to compute coefficients. I don't know enough about statistics to compare the two approaches. If you have the knowledge I'd be interested to know your take on it :-)

Comment: In case you haven't seen this yet https://rdrr.io/cran/nlme/man/corARMA.html